# Regex to get string with only one dash

Tags: regex

Sorry for the bad question title, I couldn't figure out a better one.

I need a regex, that extracts Season, Episode and Title of Tv Show Transcripts. In my file they can appear like this:

```
<span class="topic">01x02 - The Big Bran Hypothesis</span><b
<td><b>01x07 - The Dumpling Paradox</b></td>
<title>Transcripts - Forever Dreaming :: 01x07 - The Dumpling Paradox - The Big Bang Theory</title>
<title>Transcripts - Forever Dreaming :: 06x04 - The Re-Entry Minimisation - The Big Bang Theory</title>
```

I tried with:

```
([\d]+x[\d]+)\s?[-]?\s?([\w\s]*)
```

See [Regex101 Example here](https://regex101.com/r/MXZ8X8/2)

This regex matches:

```
01x02 - The Big Bran Hypothesis
01x07 - The Dumpling Paradox
01x07 - The Dumpling Paradox
06x04 - The Re
```

The issue I'm facing is, how to get the rest of the title of the last one ("The Re-Entry Minimisation") without `" - The Big Bang Theory"`.

I tried by adding a `-` in the second capturing group, but this includes the part after the title too.

I also tried to add a positive lookahead for `-` but this also can't work, as it is matching the first `-` after season and episode too.

I guess it is quite straight forward how to do this, but I can't figure it out. Anyone an idea? Thank you!

Comment: See [`(\d+x\d+)\s?-?\s?([^<]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/9IpNLa/1).

Comment: This is matching the " - The Big Bang Theory" Part also. The 4th match e.g. should be "06x04 - The Re-Entry Minimisation", not "06x04 - The Re-Entry Minimisation - The Big Bang Theory"

Comment: Regex should be applied to plain text. Yes, you might use [`(\d+x\d+)\s?-?\s?([^-<]*(?:\b-\b[^-<]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/9IpNLa/2), but it is really ugly.

Comment: I came up with `([\d]+x[\d]+)\s?[-]?((\s?\w+-?)+)` - seems to work on the example, but I bet it won´t fit on all other use cases. Not happy with this one.

Comment: The easiest - [`(\d+x\d+)\s*-\s*([^<]*?)(?=\s-|<)`](https://regex101.com/r/9IpNLa/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will successfully match a hyphenated title, while avoiding the trailing show name:
    `(\d+)x(\d+) ?- ?([-\w\s]+) -`

It will produce the following capture groups:

1. Season
2. Episode
3. Title

Breakdown:

- `(\d+)x(\d+)` matches and captures the season and episode, each in its own group
- `?- ?` matches the dash delimiter, with or without spaces
- `([-\w\s]+) -` captures any letters, dashes, and spaces, but only up to a dash with spaces around it, which seems to be the only distinction between one within the title and after it.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/y7TFTV/1) demo.

**Note:** if you really need the entire match to exclude the show name, rather than using the specific groups, just change `-` to a positive lookahead `(?= - )` so it won't match the trailing dash.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(\d{2}x\d{2} - [\w\s]*(-\w)?[\w\s]*)
```

It also returns you a second group, but you can simply ignore it. Or, actually, you can use the full match simply with

```
\d{2}x\d{2} - [\w\s]*(-\w)?[\w\s]*
```

----- EDIT -----

to be correct, the trick is to consider that words may be hyphenated while ignoring actual hyphens.

The following regex is more general and matches something like "out-of-the-box":

```
\d{2}x\d{2} - ([\w\s]*(-\w)?)*
```